# How to draw several plots and see them in one loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I couldn't print ggplots in `for` loops.
**I tried with or without `print()` function, but both didn’t work.**
I'd love to see the plots in the plot panels. I do not want to save images like png, tiff or others.
I also wonder how to see all the plots in the plot panel at once not one by one.

```
for(index in org_kmmse$question_num %>% unique()){
  org_kmmse %>% filter(question_num==index) %>%
    print(ggplot()+geom_bar(data =., aes(x = answer,fill = diag_nm))+
    labs(title = index))
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

and **I get below error message**

```
Error in max(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument`
```

Where should I change unlist function in the for loop?
P.S. `org_kmmse` dimension is 480 by 9

Comment: Try chaining the print statement to the end (after the ggplot call) with `%>% print()`

Comment: @Dave2e  I try it but it still does not work....additionally ```for(index in org_kmmse$question_num %>% unique()){
  
  p <- org_kmmse %>% filter(question_num==index) %>% 
    ggplot()+geom_bar(aes(x = answer,fill = diag_nm))+
    labs(title = index)
  print(p)
  
}``` didn't work